# foreach and this in php showing warning

Tags: php, foreach

i have a doubt.this is my foreach loop

```
<table>
<?php foreach($this->msg as $l): ?>
 <tr><td>
 <a href="index.php/downloads?id=<?php echo $l->id;?>"><?php echo $l->name;?></a>
 </td></tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
  </table>
```

where $this->msg is an array of results from db. this shows warning

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

how should i resolve this?

Comment: At the time you call this code, `$this->msg` is **not** an array. You should check its type (try `is_array`) before entering the loop or instantiate it to an empty array on declaration, eg `private $msg = array();`

Comment: use var_dump and check $this-msg value

Comment: check if $this->msg an array `var_dump($this->msg)`

Comment: when var_dump gives before <table> it returns null. but after i run the above code actually i got the correct array details from db also with the error message.

Comment: @Phil : thank you phil..i solved it using the if(empty($this->msg)) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is:

```
if(empty($this->msg)){
}
else{
<table>
<?php foreach($this->msg as $l): ?>
<tr><td>
<a href="index.php/downloads?id=<?php echo $l->id;?>"><?php echo $l->name;?></a>
</td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
 </table>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your not sure what your passing through `foreach` then i recommend you to check first using `is_array` function. Something like this:

```
if (is_array($message)) {

foreach ($message as $text) {
//do something

 }
}
```

Use `var_export` or `var_dump` to check what your passing to foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
First check output from $this->msg.
If it is array type && not empty then and then you can pass to the foreach loop.

You can check array using is_array() function
&&
You can check array is empty using empty() function.
```

-
Thanks